# Оптимизация процесса загрузки фото

Tags: wordpress

Есть WordPress-сайт на собственном сервере. На фронте добавлена форма для заведения юзером портфолио, в которое можно прикрепить до 100 фото.

В данный момент 100 фото закачиваются порядка 20 минут, а кропаются и оптимизируются 2 часа.

Для оптимизации фото используется внешний сервис https://imagify.io/.

Также при заливке у каждого фото определяются его цвета и кладутся в базу.

Как оптимизировтаь данный процесс, уменьшить время работы скрипта? Какие есть решения, плагины? Может быть, заставить кропать фотки сервером через ewww, например. Делать это отложенно по кропу. Может решением будет создание виртуальной файловой системы типа flysystem?

Поможет любая мысль, ссылка, технология, что угодно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Убрать все внешние сервисы и для оптимизации использовать [jpeg_quality](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/jpeg_quality/). 
Возможно и [add_image_size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) понадобится.

Comment: Не понял как это поможет? Это всего лишь фильтр для задания уровня компрессии у jpeg при его закачке на сервер. У нас есть PNG, GIF, WEBM, BMP. Жать это на РНР - оооочень накладно. Миниатюр создается порядка 10 размеров разных

Comment: @mihdan, зачем вам столько миниатюр, если не секрет?

Comment: Поможет как минимум тем, что сократит время на пересылку кучи картинок на сторонние сервисы и обратно.

Comment: Раньше использовали ewww плагин, он умел вызывать серверные утилиты для оптимизации, но со временем ресур стал высокопосещаемым и даже этот вариант стал тормозить и давать сбои. Сделали отложенную оптимизацию этим же плагином. Этого хватило на пару месяцев.

Comment: @SeVlad это также будет кропаться на РНР как и раньше (ресурсы жрет не хило) ток вот качество фото у нас должно быть близко к 100% - дизайнерский ресурс

Comment: @Pyramidhead шаблонов вывода каждой фото на всем сайт порядка 30ти. Виджеты, меню, сайдбары, блоки, колонки - везде разные размеры и ориентация фотографии, большинство потом подогнаны через post thumbnail editor

Comment: @mihdan, для экранов никогда не нужно 100%.:Для отображения на экране  в большинстве случаев достаточно 70-85 (а то и меньше). Тем более коде речь об миниатюрах. Под которые *всегда можно положить ссылку на оригинал* (хоть в 100% кач-ве). Это никак не ухудшит вид, но значительно сократить объёмы и увечит скорость загрузки. Что в свою очередь положительно скажется и на положение в ПС и для пользователей будет лучше. Но это уже тема другого разговора.

Comment: @SeVlad вы правы, это не имеет отношения к вопросу и является темой другого разговора. Сайту 11 лет. За это время он ни дня не оставался без оптимизаций и улучшений. Такое количесвто миниатюр просто необходимо ему для жизни. Большинство юзеров из Мск, что сидят под ретиной. Муар на фото для них смерти подобен ( Решений пока не вижу

Comment: Если у Вас появляются артефакты при дефолтном (сейчас 90) сжатии миниатюр - это плохая работа серверных библиотек. Вместо GD используйте imaging. И вообще - посмотрите на другие сайты на ВП - что, везде есть муар на миниатюрах? Что-то я сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: И да, те же вешние сервисы, если оптимизируют, то точно также. Какой смысл их использовать, перегоняя тонны траффика - я лично не понимаю. Разве что для снижения нагрузки  на свой сервер, но тут надо смотреть что в приоритете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52518/discussion-between-mihdan-and-sevlad).